# Attaching an event to CPagination change in Yii AFTER new page has been rendered

Tags: jquery, pagination, yii, event-delegation

this is probably a newbie question so i hope it will be easy to answer!! i have been struggling for nearly a week with this.. please any help is much appreciated.

I have a CListView and i am using the integrated cpagination. i have a javascript function triggered with the onload event which paints some of the items of this clistview, depending on a certain condition. however, this event isn't triggered when the user changes the page, so clearly this is a problem: since the items are only painted the very first time the page is loaded.

Now, i have gotten this far: i learned how to haandle jquery events, so i have this:

```
    $('body').delegate('li', 'click', function(event) {
    alert("next");
    paintMyLigas();
});
```

This way, each time the next, previous, or any other pagination button is clicked, then this function is called. The alerts pop up, i have even added some alerts within the paintMyLigas() function which also pop up. However, my items don't get painted again. I believe it may be because this event is triggered BEFORE the new page (of the cpagination) is rendered. Here is where i am stuck (for the nth time in this week): how can i get this event to trigger afterwards? or can anyone point out any other direction for me to be able to solve this? i need help!! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for a way to execute custom JS code after every update to the `CListView` (which is handled automatically with AJAX), then the [`afterAjaxUpdate`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView#afterAjaxUpdate-detail) property is the hook you want.

For example, try setting `afterAjaxUpdate = 'js:paintMyLigas'`. Is this what you want?

Comment: Didn`t work.. but I don`t think im updating the CListView, im just trying to go to the next page. [This post](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/15863-clistview-cant-load-javascript-in-an-itemviewphp-when-go-to-next-page/page__p__78742__hl__ajax+option+java+cript#entry78742) describes perfectly my problem, however the solution wasn`t posted clearly enough (at least for me, since i already admitted to being a newbie), and so it wasn`t enough to get me unstuck. Maybe you could help me understand it!! :) Thank you so much for answering!!